# Android.Hardware.Usb missing for dot42?

Tags: android, dot42

Looking at dot42 - I am trying to get access to the usb port. Looking at Andoird.Hardware and Usb does not exist. Any ideas? Am I missing an assembly?

Comment: Irrespective of any alternative framework, **Android as a system simply does not provide generic "access to the the USB port"**.  Instead, there are specific mechanism for interacting with specific devices or responding to certain types of external hosts.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Android.Hardware.Usb` was added in API level 12 (Android 3.1). Are you sure that you have set the Android version of your project to 3.1 or higher? You can find this setting on the Android tab of the project properties. This setting corresponds to `android:minSdkVersion` attribute of the `uses-sdk` element of the Android manifest.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for... Now on to the next roadblock.